# describe and sketch complex set

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(D)$ where $D = { z : |z|<1}$ and $f(z) = \frac{z+i}{z-1}$.

Am I right on saying this set can be described as a translation by $i$ and dilation by $\frac{1}{z-1}$?

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange to find that $$ z = \frac{f(z) + i}{f(z) - 1}.$$

Hence $|z| < 1  \Longleftrightarrow  |f(z) +i| < |f(z) - 1|.$

So $$f(D) = \{ w \in \mathbb{C} : |z+i| < |z-1|\}.$$

This is the set of complex numbers closer to $-i$ than to $1$. To draw this set, sketch the line "$y=-x$" on an Argand diagram, and shade the area strictly below this line.

Answer (score 0):

Well...not really. It's a translation by $i$ all right, but that's followed by a "dilation that depends on $z$" which isn't called a dilation - dilations are multiplication by a constant like $-3$ or $7 + 4i$.

Suppose that your problem were $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z-1}$; do you know what that would look like? What if it were $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z}$? Once you can answer those, you may be able to answer the more complex problems like the one you've given.

(I've answered the question you asked: "Am I right in saying..." rather than answering the question your homework asks; I hope that is what you wanted.)